# Code signing is failing after running unit tests

Tags: swift, unit-testing, cocoa, code-signing, xcode8

I recently updated to Xcode 8 and converted my code to Swift 3. Now my unit testing are failing, probably as they should, but then code signing are failing when trying to run again.

I use several CocoaPods, but they have worked previously. Everything work outside of UnitTesting.

The only fix I found so far is to clear <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and rebuild solution.

Does anyone have a permanent fix for this?

**Error**

```
/Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-bbpdbvqjecpwzvfliyyqcnarjvua/Build/Products/Pro Debug/***.app: replacing existing signature
/Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-bbpdbvqjecpwzvfliyyqcnarjvua/Build/Products/Pro Debug/***.app: code object is not signed at all
In subcomponent: /Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-bbpdbvqjecpwzvfliyyqcnarjvua/Build/Products/Pro Debug/***.app/Contents/PlugIns/***Tests.xctest
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

***Edit***: When running UnitTests which are all successful the code signing still fails on second run. Basically I have to clean the build before each test run.

Comment: Are you using any pods in your project..What problem are you getting exactly.can you specify...

Comment: Yes - I use several pods. I updated my question with specific error.

Comment: Clearly, I see you have code signing issue.I had a similar issues after moved to Xcode 8. I think Xcode policy has been changed when you using pod.you have to physically code sign your pod project or modify the pod file to bypass code signing.look at the question I posted in stack overflow from the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39945377/no-code-signature-found-after-pod-installed-in-xcode-8 if the post works give me thump up.hope you will find the answer.

Comment: I'm commenting because I have a similar issue with a Swift Mac OS app on XCode 11 - unit tests were running fine, then after some project changes they now get a codesign error on build when trying to run tests - but the app codesigns fine, and both are set to automatic code-signing. None of the suggestions below have fixed it, but I did find that going back in source control I can reach a version that still succeeds at running tests, so it's definitely a project issue (but *not* a codesign-settings or certificate issue) - will follow up when I isolate the change that causes the failure.

Comment: for me, the answer was to 1) turn off all codesigning on the test target. 2) build, test. 3) clean build folder, 4) turn on auto-signing for test targed. 5) clean build folder, 6) all good.
Some steps probably not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to go to the Pods project in the workspace, and turn on code signing on the pod targets.

This either turned on some missing setting from the Swift 3 migration or this is the actual solution.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to go to the test target and turn on "Automatically manage signing." My app already had automatic signing turned on, so I'm thinking something is amiss in Xcode when automatic signing is not turned on for the test target as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to share one other solution here, based on my comment above, that seems to primarily affect Mac OS app projects (not iOS) with the same symptom: codesign failure of the test target, when the app target codesigns fine, with automatic codesigning enabled for both.

None of the other solutions worked - my issue did not seem to involve the codesign configuration at all. Somehow the inclusion of UI classes in the non-UI test target and dependency on the app target triggers the codesign failure.

The fix in this case is:

1. Make sure all classes that have UI dependency (NSViewController, etc.) are *not* compiled in the non-UI test target
2. In the test target settings Build Phases->Dependencies, *remove* the app target from the test target's dependencies.

These two steps enabled me to again run non-UI unit tests without the code signing error in Xcode 11.

Answer (score 0):

Being consistent in the .xcodeproj I think is the right answer here.  For my project, which is a macOS project, compiling for 10.15+ on Xcode 12, when I made a new test target, it Checked `Automatically Manage Signing`, even though my other schemes were unchecked, and I was handling it all manually.

So I unchecked `Automatically Manage Signing`, and then under `Build Settings -> Code Signing Identity` of the Test target, select `Other` from the dropdown.  Then make sure that this `-` dash line is deleted.  From there it successfully built for me.