# Unable to install IPA in device after cocoapods integratation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am able to generate the ipa but unable to install it in device after I integrated the pods.

XCode version: 8.0
Base SDK: 10.0
Cocoa pods version: 1.1.1

Comment: check your device version

Comment: I had similar issue after moved to Xcode 8.In Xcode 8 apple policy changed to using pod.did you code sign your pod project?

Comment: How to do that Joe?

Comment: Same profile I need to use while generating the ipa? I will verify that

Comment: I am not sure is that the problem in your case. But worth looking at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39945377/no-code-signature-found-after-pod-installed-in-xcode-8

Answer (score 0):

Check following,
1. Have you added your device UDID in provisional profile?
2. Have you used correct profile to generate the ipa?
3. Check your device version meet out your app's minimum deployment target.
4. Make sure you generated the ipa properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed framework search paths and re-generated the ipa and it worked.