# How to turn off code signing on third-party iOS frameworks with CocoaPods?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I've added the Tesseract iOS library to my Swift project via CocoaPods, but I'd like to turn off code signing for development on a simulator. I've added "Don't Sign" to the settings on the project and my targets, but builds continue to have a code signing step. There's also some code in my Podfile that tries to turn off code signing.

In the build log, I see

```
Code Signing /Users/ME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECT-fchynlbfcpjfbcfaplehdrryfpqn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PROJECT.app/Frameworks/TesseractOCR.framework with Identity -
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign -  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements "/Users/ME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECT-fchynlbfcpjfbcfaplehdrryfpqn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PROJECT.app/Frameworks/TesseractOCR.framework"
```

The podfile looks something like this:

```ruby
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'PROJECT' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'TesseractOCRiOS', :git => "git@github.com:gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS.git"
  target 'PROJECTTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = ""
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Are you sure you trying to run in simulator or iPhone ?. You don't need to code sign your project .If you running  in simulator .code signing only requires when you test your project in device.i assume you using Xcode 8.if yes, you have to code sign your pod project manually.(apple policy been changed in Swift 3.when you using pods). Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks, Joe. Yes, it's Xcode 8 and on the simulator. It's also the latest version of Swift, and I am, like I mentioned, using pods. I also thought that code signing wasn't required for the simulator, but I think perhaps my Tesseract framework dependency is forcing it? Is this possible? If so, how can I turn it off?

Comment: Check my post. It may give you a  hint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39945377/no-code-signature-found-after-pod-installed-in-xcode-8